# How do I insulate a living area below a former porch

Tags: insulation

My brother has an old house probably built in the 30s or 40s  in renovated in the 50s. The very front of the house looks like it may have been a converted porch. There was recently a leak which prompted me to pull down some of the sheet rock on the ceiling. I was a little surprised to see that there is no insulation at all above that area ( which explains the heating bills ).

I’m wondering what the best way to insulate the area is. The roof is at about a 20 degree angle, do I insulate the area about the Sheetrock, or the angles of the eves? How do I make sure everything is vented correctly ?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you OK with insulating this from above? What are ground snow loads like in your area?

Comment: To insulate from above I would have to tear the roof off, don’t know the snow loads but it has held up for 50 years the way it was constructed

Comment: Ignoring the ventilation issue, I would use 6" batts or rolls with a vapor barrier, installed with the vapor barrier down (towards the living space).  That will give you an R-19 value with typical batt material (fiberglass, rockwool), which will reduce your heat leakage through the roof by ~95%.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the insulation is on top of the sheetrock, and venting takes place just below the roof boards, or anyway between the roof boards and the top of the insulation - unless you have a lot of space to work with, more insulation is better up until you block the venting, and then it's not.

Given that it's a "converted porch" the high side of the venting may be difficult, or at least involve getting creative, if it butts up against a wall rather than connecting to a vented attic - in which case you'll need to install vents on the top part of the roof surface. Intake vents at the eaves/soffits should be more normal.

Buildings of that age, never assume with respect to insulation - there may be other areas completely lacking it that you'd expect to be insulated.

Comment: It is butted against the building, and its a hipped roof making the high side even more challenging, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Rolled insulation with a vapor (paper) face if the room is an enclosed space not open to exterior. Or if there is a living space above it.

If the room is enclosed with solid walls you should install the insulation with the paper face to the inside.

If your insulating a room above the porch install with the paper face away from the porch.

Unless the room is being conditioned (heated or cooled) there is little reason to insulate.

Comment: Its a single level addition that has nothing above accept roof